# How do I change the background color for code block in jekyll?

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I'm playing with Jekyll, and have been able to change the background colour for my site. However, no matter which background or background-color properties I change in `_syntax-highlighting.scss`, I still get the same light grey background (even if I restart the jekyll server).

None of the css/sass default files seem obvious to me for this, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_sass/base.scss` and change `pre, code` rule :

```
pre,
code {
    ...
    background-color: #eef;
}
```

Comment: No, I've already changed the default background. That was easy. I was asking how you change the background for the code snippet blocks.

Comment: Get it ! Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by David Jacquel did not work for me.

What worked for me is following;

Go to this file `/static/css/main.css` and change the parameters for `pre`.

`Background` is the background color for the code block, `color` is the font color in it.

Somehow, `.highlight` parameters dominate over `pre` parameters. I commented out as well `.highlight` section. This is how the final code looks like.

```
/* Content */
div.content pre {
 background: #d42525;
 padding: 10px;
 color: rgb(20, 199, 29);
 overflow-x: auto;
 font-family: Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace;
 font-size: 12px;
 border: none;
}
/* Removed this part to be able to change background of "pre" */
/* div.content .highlight { 
 background: #333333;
} */
```

You can see how the code block looks like with those parameters from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwRcQ.png)