# How to change code snippet background in Jekyll blog

Tags: html, jekyll

I want to change the background of my code snippets from black to something lighter (like light grey.) I have already tried the suggestion from this [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422103/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-for-code-block-in-jekyll) which suggests to change the _base.scss in the _sass folder.  As you can see from my _base.scss, the code snippet background is specified already as #eef, which is a lighter color.  However, my blog does not obey that color.

```
/**
 * Code formatting
 */
pre,
code {
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 1px solid $grey-color-light;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #eef;
}
```

I then looked in another file called _variables.scss located in the same _sass file.  The code contained in that file is this:

```
// Inline code block font color
$codeblock-font-color: #8cc4d8;

// Inline code block background color
$codeblock-background-color: #333333;
```

It looks like this would be the place to change my code snippet background from dark (#333333) to something else lighter like #F5F5F5 (HTML White Smoke) however, when I tried that, again, the blog does not obey.

When writing my code in the markdown file, I use the three backticks.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: I was overwriting multiple CSS's in my css/main.css syntax - I deleted the superfluous

```
div.content .highlight {
    background: #333333;
```

located in my css/main.css and now am able to change the background color in the field after background:

```
div.content pre {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  overflow-x: auto;
  font-family: Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
}
```